# .NET ProcessFrameWork reference not given value for parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, sdk, visual-studio-2019

I've never seen this issue before and I'm not sure what happened it was working last night. Now my projects aren't building. I've redownloaded Visual Studio

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is this error reported after building the project? Did you change some settings before this error?